# Firebase Unintended data is written when logging in

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm making a simple TODO app.
Strange behavior when running this code in Firebase.

1. Login as user A
2. Add todo "aaaa"
3. Logout
4. Login as user B
5. Strange phenomenon（TODO added by user A is automatically synchronized with B）

I think some kind of CASH is occurring in firestore, but I can't initialize it.
I want you to tell me the cause.

### demo site

https://todo-99094.web.app/

### html

```
      <button id="login-btn">login</button>
      <button id="logout-btn">logout</button>
      <input type="text" id="add-text">
      <button id="add-btn">add</button>
      <div id="todos">
        <!--TODO add-->
      </div>
```

### javascript

```
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var db = firebase.firestore();
      var todos=[];

      console.log("DOMContentLoaded")

      //-----------------------------------
      // 画面への追加 と Firestoreへの追加を行う
      // firestore_witeはクラウドへの書き込みを行うかどうか？
      function add(text,firestore_wite=false){
        todos.push(text)

        var div = document.createElement('div'); // 追加する基礎要素作成

        var btn = document.createElement('button');// 基礎要素の配下に削除ボタンの作成
        btn.textContent="削除"
        btn.addEventListener('click',function(event){
          todos.splice((todos.indexOf(text)),1);
          div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
          firebase_wite(todos);
        })

        div.textContent = text;//表示文字の追加
        div.appendChild(btn);

        document.getElementById('todos').appendChild(div);
        if(firestore_wite){
          firebase_wite(todos);// Firebaseへの書き込み
        }
      }
      //-----------------------------------
      // 表示データ削除
      function v_flash(){
        document.getElementById('todos').textContent = null;
        todos=[]
      }
      //-----------------------------------
      // Firestoreへのデータ書き込み
      function firebase_wite(d){
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            // 下記のようなイメージのデータを書き込む
            // datas>(user.id)>{data:[(data)]}
              var cnf = db.collection("datas").doc(user.uid).set({data:d}).then(function(docRef) {
                console.log("wite data: ", d,"userid:",user.uid);
              }).catch(function(error) {
                console.error("error wite document: ", error);
              });
          }else{
              console.log("1no login")
          }
        });
      }

      //-----------------------------------
      // Firestoreからのデータ読み込み
      // 非同期であるため、引数に関数を渡して、成功したら呼び出す形
      function firebase_read(user,cb){
        // todo read
          if (user) {
            // 下記のようなイメージのデータを読み込む
            // datas>(user.id)>{data:[(data)]}
            db.collection("datas").doc(user.uid).get().then(function(doc) {
                if (doc.exists) {
                    console.log("user",user.uid,"get data:",doc.data().data);
                    cb&&cb(doc.data().data)//呼び出し元が指定した関数の呼び出し
                } else {
                    console.log("no document!");
                }
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log("error read document:", error);
            });
          }else{
              console.log("2no login")
          }
      }

      //-----------------------------------
      // Firestoreからのデータ読み込みを行い、UIに更新する。
      function read(user){
        firebase_read(user,function(d){
          d.forEach(function(i){
            add(i,false);// firestoreから読み込まれた結果であるため、追記はしない
            console.log("read:",i)
          });
        })
      }
      //-----------------------------------
      // ログイン済みかどうかを確認する
      // ログイン済みの場合は、UIを更新する
      function login_chack(){
        var flag=0;
          firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if(flag==0){
                console.log("flag0",flag++)
                v_flash();//要素を全部削除
                if (user) {
                  console.log("login_chack:login")
                  read(user);
                  document.getElementById('login-btn').setAttribute('hidden', 'true');//login ボタンを消す
                  document.getElementById('logout-btn').removeAttribute('hidden');//logout ボタンを出す
                }else{
                  console.log("login_chack:no login")
                  document.getElementById('login-btn').removeAttribute('hidden');//login ボタンを出す
                  document.getElementById('logout-btn').setAttribute('hidden', 'true');//logout ボタンを消す
                }
              }
          });            
        }

      //-----------------------------------
      // ログインボタンのクリックイベント
      document.getElementById("login-btn").onclick = function() {
            var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
            provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
            var flag=0;
            // google ログイン処理
            firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
              if(flag==0 && result.user){
                console.log("flag1",flag++)
                login_chack();
              }
            }).catch(function(e) {
              if(flag){
                console.log("flag2",flag++)
                console.log(`login err :`,e);
                login_chack();
              }
            });
        };

      //-----------------------------------
      // ログアウトボタンのクリックイベント
      document.getElementById("logout-btn").onclick = function() {
          var flag=0;
          firebase.auth().signOut().then(()=>{
            if(flag==0){
              console.log("flag3",flag++)
              console.log("logout-btn:logout");
              login_chack();
            }
          })
          .catch( (e)=>{
            if(flag){
              console.log("flag4",flag++)
              console.log(`logout-btn:err:`,e);
              login_chack();
            }
          });
        };

      //-----------------------------------
      // 追加ボタンのクリックイベント
      document.getElementById("add-btn").onclick = function() {
            add(document.getElementById("add-text").value,true);
        };
        login_chack()//起動時のログインチェク
  });
```

### ruhru

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /datas/{userID} {
      allow read write: if request.auth.uid == userID;
   }
  }
}
```

### logs(1)

[image]

### logs(2)

[image]

Comment: Are you actually logging in and out using Firebase authentication anywhere? I don't see that in your code.

Comment: login is `document.getElementById("login-btn").onclick = function() {` event.
logout is `document.getElementById("logout-btn").onclick = function() {` event.
I am doing in that. Is there a problem with the method?

Comment: Can you check this piece of code `firebase.auth().signOut(` is being called when the users signs out? Also can you elaborate on what this *TODO added by user A is automatically synchronized with B* means? What is 'synchronized' and how do you know that's happening?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
`firebase.auth().signOut(` has been called. Then, checking with `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` shows that the user is logged out.

Firestore manages data on a per-user basis.
The program is designed so that Mr. A cannot manipulate Mr. B's data. However, if you log in as Mr. A and then log in as Mr. B, your Firestore data will be automatically overwritten by Mr. A's data.

Comment: Firestore does not manage data on a per user basis and there is no tie between users and data what-so-ever. Firestore data is just data, users are just users. Any user can read/write any data at any time. The bridge between users and data are Firebase Rules and your apps code. Data being overwritten will only happen if you write to a document using the same document ID. The one thing I am seeing is that when data is written, you get the current user `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` but when data is read `function read(user)` it may be using a stale user object? I am not a java expert.

Comment: Thank you.
I understand about ruhru regarding data access on Firestore.
Check it out as I've added the rules I'm setting up now.
The problem occurs when a new user logs in. 
The new user's data is overwritten by the old user's data.
Added a demo page.
It may be easier to understand if you give it a try.
I guarantee that the information on this page will be removed.

Comment: I think the issue is on v_flash() and how you are using it. You are calling v_flash() on login_chack() but I think you also need to use the v_flash() on firebase_read(user,cb) before you load the data at the if (user) statement.

Comment: Looking at your logs, a user logs in with a uid ending in Zcr1 and that data is written to their node. That user logs out and then a second user logs in with uid ending in auL2 and writes data to their node then user logs out. Then the FIRST user logs in again with uid ending ins Zcr1. Based on that and the node being written to, I am not seeing any data being overwritten from another user; user Zcr1 writes their respective node and user auL2 writes to their node. What's the issue?

Comment: Thank you all.
 I fixed the position of `v_flash()`, but it didn't fix the problem.
Modify to output a variable to Log when reading.
If you look at this, you can see that the value from the last time you logged in is included in the timing of the first Read.
However, the callback has been called out more than I imagined.
The design needs to be rethought.